# Ignore optional leading string when sorting

Tags: bash, sorting

Is there an efficient way to sort a file while ignoring a string that appears at the beginning of some lines?

For example, say I have a list of files like this:

```
FileAardvark
FileBee
N-FileBear
N-FileCat
FileZebra
```

And I want to sort while ignoring the "N-", so the sorted result would be

```
FileAardvark
N-FileBear
FileBee
N-FileCat
FileZebra
```

I need to not edit the lines directly, otherwise I could just strip the 'N-' from the file entirely. My initial thought was to use 'N-' as a delimiter to `sort`, but that fails both because 'N-' is multiple characters and because then the column number I need then differs from line to line.

In my particular case, it happened that all the strings started with the same term (i.e., as in the example, everything has "File" at the beginning) and I needed to sort on the entirety of the remaining line, so I ended up using this `sed`/`sort` chain, which got me the result I wanted:

`sed -e 's/File/\x06/g' | sort -t$'\x06' -k2 | sed -e 's/\x06/File/g'`

However, I can't depend on having a duplicated sequence at the beginning of all the strings relevant to the sorting, so how can I accomplish this in a more general way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easy approach is to prepend a field with the `N-` stripped to the front of your line, sort that stream, then strip that prefix off.

With GNU sed (having `-r`; with MacOS or another modern BSD `sed` substitute `-E`):

```
sed -r -e 's/^((N-)?([^ ]*))/\3 \1/' <<<"$str" | sort | sed -r -e 's/[^ ]+ //'
```

...this is very similar to the preferred approach to sorting files by modification time -- which places the modification time before each name in a NUL-delimited stream (since NUL is the only character which cannot exist in a file's pathname), sorts by that initial field, then strips it off.

Comment: I think I'm following this correctly. In other words: extract `$string_to_sort_by` (the `\3` in the first `sed`), prepend `$string_to_sort_by$delimeter` to each line, sort, then strip beginning of line to `$delimeter`. Right?

Comment: Spot on. Need to be sure that your delimiter won't exist in string_to_sort_by, but that's the only limitation.